# Getting a date + 3 days ( using specific date) SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to get the next available day after a result set.

This is the query I'm using but is totally wrong:

```
SELECT DateID = ROW_NUMBER() over (order by B.Date_Key) , B.ClosingDate, C.dates AS RecDay
        FROM DIM_DATE B JOIN [dbo].[WorkDay_Calendar] C  on C.dates = DATEADD(DAY,3, B.ClosingDate)  WHERE YEAR(B.ClosingDate) >= '2018' 
             AND C.[Sentday] = 0 and C.[RecDay] = 0
```

This query is
retrieving the RecDay when Closingdate +3 days = to Sentday AND What I want is 
when Closingdate + 3(Sentday) then pick the next RecDay,
something like `C.dates = DATEADD(DAY,3(Sentday), B.ClosingDate)`.

This is how are looking my tables:

Dim_Date table

[image]

WorkDay_Calendar Table

[image]

Notice that when Sentday and RecDay are valid when = 0 if 1 is not valid because is a weekend or holiday.

Based on this information for example if I pick from the Dim_Date table 2018-02-02 as one of the Closingdate then the RecDay should be:

```
DateID       RecDay
------------------------
1            2018-02-07
```

And with the current query is retrieving this which is totally wrong:

```
DateID       RecDay
-----------------------
1            2018-02-05
```

Graphic explanation below and please follow the 0 in Bold:

[image]

More output examples:
Using the dates below as ClosingDate:

```
Date_Key           ClosingDate:
38284              2018-07-24
38287              2018-01-10
38290              2018-03-08
38291              2018-07-13
38293              2018-02-08
```

Using the same order of the ClosingDates these should be the outputs, I incluided the ClosingDate column so you can follow the order:
OUTPUTS:

```
DateID      ClosingDate      RecDay (output)
1           2018-07-24       2018-07-30
2           2018-01-10       2018-01-16
3           2018-03-08       2018-03-13
4           2018-07-13       2018-07-18
5           2018-02-08       2018-02-13
```

Comment: Can you provide sample "input" data? It's not clear what you are working with.

Comment: It is already there.

Comment: No it isn't already there. You listed some values for columns which is not the same thing as what your tables actually contain. Keep in mind we don't know your tables or what you are trying to accomplish here. What you need to post is something so that others can help you. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Ok, now is edited with tables descriptions let me know if that helps.

Comment: So receive day is 5 days before it is sent? I don't really understand what you are trying to do here to be honest.

Comment: Sorry, it was wrong values.

Comment: So are you saying that if you don't have a value in CalendarTable for the ClosingDate in DIM_DATE that you get the next available date?

Comment: Exactly, for every closingDate count 3 next days using the Sent day for that and after that count pick the next available day from the receiveday field.

Comment: Please Let me know if you can understand now.

Comment: All set, please let me know if it make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure If if followed you correctly, but based on your condition, you want to check the date dimension table based on calendar table. If ClosingDate + 3 days is equal to SentDay then you need to get the ReceiveDay. if that's what you need. then try this out :

**UPDATED**

```
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Date_key) DateID, 
    ClosingDateOLD,
    C.Dates
FROM (
SELECT
    Date_key,
    ClosingDate AS ClosingDateOLD,
    CASE 
        WHEN  DATENAME(dw, DATEADD(DAY, 4, ClosingDate)) IN ('Saturday') THEN DATEADD(DAY, 6, ClosingDate)
        WHEN  DATENAME(dw, DATEADD(DAY, 4, ClosingDate)) IN ('Sunday')   THEN DATEADD(DAY, 5, ClosingDate)
        ELSE  DATEADD(DAY, 5, ClosingDate)
    END AS ClosingDate
FROM 
    @DIM_DATE
WHERE 
    ClosingDate IS NOT NULL 
) D 
JOIN @Calendar C ON C.Dates = ClosingDate
```

Comment: haha nearly identical code posted just a few seconds before mine. :)

Comment: @SeanLange do you believe in telepathy ? :)

Comment: I might have to start believing. ;)

Comment: @JCACERES add this to the join `AND DATENAME(dw, ClosingDate) NOT IN ('Friday','Saturday')` see if is it what you want

Comment: I just made some edits, let me know if you know if you can understand now.

Comment: @JCACERES I've updated the query. It should now gives you what you want.

Comment: @iSR5 in the formula it should add 3 days from the SentDay not a regular day.

Comment: @JCACERES check the second update, I hope this is what you're looking for

Comment: @iSR5 still no, the point here is when adding Dateadd function it should add the next 3 days but Using the SentDay*

Comment: @JCACERES so you need to add 3 days to sentDay along with closingdate ?

Comment: 3 days from sentDay, something like C.dates = DATEADD(DAY,3(Sentday), B.ClosingDate), but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: @JCACERES I'm trying to understand what you need but you put me in a puzzle here. If you just edit your post, and add the expected results from the sample you've provided, this will be really helpful, and will reduce the time and effort of explaining things.

Comment: @iSR5 I already have an example please see when I say...  Based on this information for example if I pick from the Dim_Date table 2018-02-02 as one of the Closingdate then the RecDay should be:

Comment: @JCACERES I've seen it, but it's not enough, I'm asking for more expected results from the provided example (at least 5 records) so we can understand the output you're expecting. The previous answers all are correct even Sean Lange answer's should be correct as well based on the output you've provided. So, in order to help, you need to add more results that cover your full question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173823/discussion-between-jcaceres-and-isr5).

Answer (score 1):

As I understand the requirements it would be something like this.

I am posting a full working example in case somebody wants to take a crack at this.

```
create table #DIM_DATE
(
    DateKey int
    , ClosingDate date
)

insert #DIM_DATE values
(1, NULL)
, (2, '2018-01-02')
, (3, NULL)
, (4, NULL)

create table #CalendarTable
(
    ID int
    , SentDay date
    , ReceiveDay date
)

insert #CalendarTable values
(1, '2018-01-03', '2018-01-02')
, (2, '2018-01-04', '2018-01-03')
, (3, '2018-01-05', '2018-01-08')


SELECT DateID = ROW_NUMBER() over (order by d.DateKey)
    , ct.ReceiveDay
FROM #DIM_DATE d
join #CalendarTable ct on ct.SentDay = dateadd(day, 3, d.ClosingDate)


drop table #DIM_DATE
drop table #CalendarTable
```

Comment: OK. You are going to need to elaborate on "still no working". What is the issue?

Comment: It seems like the count is doing based on any day but what I really want is to count the (SentDay) meaning ClosingDate + 3 Sentday.

Comment: There is no count in there. Perhaps you should share some details about what is incorrect. It is still not really clear what you want as output, I was making an educated guess. Seems that it isn't quite right but not sure what would be.

Comment: I really don't want to take more sample data and convert it something I can use so I can answer a question that has been lacking clarity (apparently on multiple sites). The desired output you stated you wanted is exactly what is returned here. There is obviously some logic you are not explaining.

Comment: Ok, I as you can see in the image I added, If the ClosingDate is on 1/2/2018 Yellow, then count 3 next days (SentDay=0) Orange one is the SentDay, then pick the next ReceiveDay =0 (1/8/2018) Blue. Please let me know if you I need to explain more.

Comment: No this makes even less sense than before. Suddenly you have a whole bunch of rows being returned. This makes absolutely no sense at all what you are wanting returned. You should write down the business rules as text because the data you have is just becoming more confusing.